Visual Studio Code: prevent defaulted terminal reuse (by tasks)
When Visual Studio Code 1.92 runs a shell task, it opens a terminal. When the task completes, the terminal is left open so the output remains visible. The terminal tells the user that pressing a key will close it, but also explains that the terminal may be reused:

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

…or in French:

Le terminal sera réutilisé par les tâches, appuyez sur une touche pour le fermer.

This can cause confusion if such "reuse" occurs, since the terminal can then show the output of several commands rather than just the latest one (despite the title). In long output, missing that could waste a lot of time, for example if you're looking at a container's log when you actually meant to look for another container's log.
As VS Code's tasks documentation indicates, the presentation.panel property allows to prevent reuse, but that setting is per-task. But I can't find a realistic way to entirely avoid that. Is there no global setting to disable that (at least for tasks which don't specify a different behavior)?
